# Python GCP API not able to read environmental values

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dlp

Developing a DLP client and Setting `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` using win shell.

API is failing with following signature:

`google.auth.exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError: File "XXXXX.json" was not found.`

When set in code using

`os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = "XXXXX.json"` it works fine.

OS used windows 10.

Can any one explain the reason?

**Updates**

1. I did set environment variable from pycharm terminal.
2. I am running the code from pycharm terminal: `python my_code.py`
3. When i print(os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]) i get the value i did set.

Comment: I recommend verifying it's set by logging them using
print(os.environ)

Comment: Yeah its getting set, verified using print(os.environ).

Comment: Did you reboot? (Windows magic tips!!!). Else, how are you running your code? You talk about win shell. Do you run it in command line? With your IDE?

Comment: Are you setting it with an absolute or relative path?

Comment: @DustinIngram I am using absolute path. I used the same path in both the scenarios.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I am running the code from pycharm terminal. I did set the env variables there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Issue Found:**

Environmental variable was set using quotes.
It should be without quotes.

`set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="path\to\secret\key"`

Confusing debug message

`google.auth.exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError: File "path\to\secret\key" was not found.`

**Resolution:**

`set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=path\to\secret\key`